# Trying to use Selenium RC

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests

I'm pretty newbie to selenium.
Im trying to configure selenium for a project in my university like the one configured with phppgadmin. 
There is no .jar file, I dont need to run anything, dont even need to install libraries, etc... I dont know if this is a RC Server or Webdriver.

Also, I want to use the PHPUnit format, cause this way I can just export test cases from the Firefox Selenium IDE plugin. There is a way to do that? 
There is a lot of information, webdrivers, etc in Internet but I believe the way phppgadmin do this is the best way.

Comment: What does phppgadmin have to do with Selenium, again? Are you saying that you want to install Selenium the same way phppgadmin is installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for something quick and dirty Selenium 1 imported off of the IDE is probably for you. If in the future you plan on continuing your university project I would highly recommend learning about Selenium Webdriver (Selenium 2).

Just as a small aside: You can export your tests from the selenium IDE in any language you desire, PHP is just one of the many choices that include (Java (JUnit), Java (TestNG), Ruby, and Python). If you're interested in PHPUnit look here http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/selenium.html, this will give you the back drop on how to start coding your Selenium Tests.

If you're going to be using the selenium RC you want to go to http://seleniumhq.org/download/. Download Selenium server. You start the server with a java -jar command. So java -jar /path/to/sel/selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar. This will start the RC server and when you're interested in running some tests execute the tests and then selenium server will take care of the rest